# How to hide similar data on datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, datatables, twig

I have table which is managed by the plugin called Datatables. Some rows are identical and I want to hide it except one, and make the sum of the column(D) where we find numbers. Look at my picture to better understand.

Comment: Generally people like to see that you've attempted solutions to this problem and what these attempts are. If you're not going to go through the effort to try to solve the problem a lot of folks won't bother either.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a django project. I think you are mixing up presentation and logic, which goes against most djangoisms. It would be **much** cleaner and more simple to do this in python and pass the unique set to the DOM set instead of doing this client side and dealing with the datatables API. But if you want to really slog through the jquery, it is possible, but probably won't be very clean.

You can probably do some magic in the column initialization. If that's too much, you could loop through the table when it's drawn, and then remove the rows

```
$('#table2excel').on('draw.dt', function(){ 
    $(this).find('tr').each(function(e) { 
     //do row comparison
  }
})
```

The problems here are, this is only called on 'draw' and if you're doing paging, it may page strange numbers (if you take 2 of the 10, it will probably just show you 8) so the paging will be weird.

Since you haven't actually shown any evidence of trying, that is all I can really give you but should be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: I'm not using paging - paging:false, I tried and my problem is i have just discovered js/jquery a couple weeks and datatables 4 days ago and i haven't finished to learn it. This is Symfony project.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using grouping in DataTables.
There isn't actual an official grouping function by DataTables but it's possible to create a custom one using [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback).

Take a look at this example from [row grouping - DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html) :

```
   var table = $('#table2excel').DataTable( {
    paging:false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ],
    "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
        var last=null;

        api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
            if ( last !== group ) {
                $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                    '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                );

                last = group;
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

The drawCallback is a Function that is called every time DataTables performs a draw.
So you can create a custom function of your own that will iterate over all the rows and will look for those identical value and if there is a match then combine the values you wanted + delete both rows and add the `grouped` row of them.

Comment: Sorry to answer too late. Thank for your solution i want not use grouping, i want to hide duplicate rows as mentionned previously plus i the grouping is not correct. See here : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/504869tabE.png

Comment: You didn't understand the solution. You need a custom function of your own!put your logic in the draw callback function.